# I have a MacBook And An iPhone . Can I make and publish an android app without any android phone and windows computer . If yes then how?

Tags: android, iphone, macos

I have a MacBook And An iPhone . Can I make and publish an android app without any android phone and windows computer . If yes then how ?

Comment: Yes. The same way you do it on Windows.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide Android Studio, etc. Did you try something? Why should "Android linked to Windows"? They aren't from the same company.

Comment: Do I Need An Android Phone To Make This ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Windows to create an Android app.

Just install Android Studio that is available on MacOs, Windows and Linux.

To test the app you can use emulators (you can find them inside Android Studio)

Comment: Do I Need An Android Phone To Make This ?

Comment: No just Android Studio